# Can't run Python from cmd line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a programming (and Python) novice. I am unable to run any python script in command prompt of my WinXP 64-bit laptop. I assigned the path and confirmed it by typing set path. I have Python32.
I get the following message:

```
>>>python hello.py

File <”stdin”> , Line1
  Python hello.py
             ^
SyntaxError: Invalid syntax
```

Following is the script I tried:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
message = "Hello, world!"
print(message)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should type this

```
python hello.py
```

at the dos/cmd prompt, not inside the Python Interpreter

Comment: I started learning python (on a windows machine) today and spend my first 30 mins searching for this answer. Thank you. Other tutorials etc. just expect a noob to know this, as if this would be some inherited information hardcoded into everyone's brain at the time of birth. Ha Ha Ha. Thanks again, also like your name :)

Answer (score 5):

Do it like this:

Go the directory(python32 in my example) and type `python hello.py`.

If you only type `python` in cmd then it'll launch the python interpreter after that `python hello.py` will return Syntax error.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing it inside the interpreter is by just importing the name of the module without the .py so for example, in your case:

```
>>>import hello
```

would return

```
Hello, World!
```

Answer (score 0):

You are typing the command inside the Python shell, do it from the DOS prompt.

I.e.,

```
 C:\somepath\> python hello.py
```

since you already have the python executable on the path (the number 1 problem usually when things don't work), you should be set to go.

Comment: @info-nowise ha ha .. yes, it's not quite higgs-boson, but Python definitely is cool :)

Answer (score 0):

`python` is the command you use to run the script so you run it in the shell. In Windows, that would be the command prompt (Run > "cmd").

Answer (score 0):

You're inside the python interpreter not the windows command line.

To open the windows command line go to

**Start -> All Programs -> Accessories -> Command Prompt**

Then you will need to change into the directory where you have stored hello.py.
If it was on your desktop you would do:

```
cd Desktop
```

and then after that you could do:

```
python hello.py
```

and it would work.