# CMD won't display my .py file

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can’t run Python from cmd line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11354090/cant-run-python-from-cmd-line)

I've decided on learning Python, and I'm running Windows 7 Starter Edition on an Acer Aspire One netbook. I installed `Python 2.7` directly under the `C:/ directory`.

I've added it to the `PATH`. When I type Python in the `CMD`, I get the appropriate message, talking about my version.

I made a file via Programmer's Notepad containing the following:

```
print "Hello world"
```

That is all I typed, and saved it as `hello.py` on my desktop.

I opened up CMD, and typed `hello.py` expecting to have Hello World pop up, but there is just a blank line, then prompts a command again.

Here is exactly what happens.

```
C:\Users\Shane>hello.py

C:\Users\Shane>
```

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Also make sure that the file name is truely `hello.py` and not `hello.py.txt` or something of that nature. Win 7 may hide the extension.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I tried that and I still have a blank line

Comment: @user1927382 better post the screenshots here.

Answer (score 2):

1) You saved your `hello.py` to your Desktop, but then you are running it from your home directory. That should actually produce an error

2) Try running it like this from your desktop:  `python Desktop\hello.py`

Comment: By default it says C:\Users\Shane> so how do I add desktop into the mix? (noob alert)

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: OP says they added "IT" to the path. I assumed they added python to the path so it finds the `python` command. I did not take that to mean that Desktop was added to the path

Comment: Just use the cd command:   cd Desktop

Comment: Or run:  python Desktop\hello.py